# FFPLAY - loop sound until signal received

Tags: bash, shell-script, ffmpeg

I have a bash script which starts `ffplay` in background, looping a short sound sample indefinitely. Then it does some other work, and finally it kills ffplay.

```
foo() {
    ffplay -loop 0 sound.wav &>/dev/null &
    trap "kill $!" RETURN

    (do work...)
}
```

I want ffplay to finish playing the currently played sample, and only then die. Is this possible?

Comment: One thing you could try is to have `ffplay` without `-loop 0` but inside a loop that checks whether `work` has completed. Your main thread would be the `ffplay` one.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani That would introduce an unacceptable delay between the individual playbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get continuous statistics or debug output from `ffplay` which
consists of lines ending carriage-return (^M) like this:

```
    nan M-A:    nan fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   ^M
  -0.07 M-A: -0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   ^M
  -0.01 M-A: -0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   ^M
   0.02 M-A:  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   ^M
```

It seems the first column is "nan", not-a-number, or negative at the start
of a loop. You could check for this and kill the process when it is seen.
The following bash script demonstrates this.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sound=somefile.wav
touch flagfile
(sleep 4; rm -f flagfile) &
ffplay -nodisp -stats -loop 0 "$sound" 2>&1 |
while read -d $'\r' time rest
do  case $time in
    nan|-*|0.00) [ ! -f flagfile ] && exit ;;
    esac
done
```

It creates a file `flagfile`, which you need to remove to say you want to
stop the loop. In this demo, it is just done after 4 seconds.
`ffplay` is run with option `-stats`. The statistics are written on stderr so we
redirect that to stdout with `2>&1`.
The statistics are piped to a while loop that uses `read` with
delimiter carriage-return (`$'\r'`) putting the first word in variable
`time` and the rest in `rest`.

The `case` compares the first word with the pattern `nan` or anything
beginning with `-`, or the number 0, and if the flagfile no longer exists,
the script exits.

After a few more writes of statistics, ffplay will be killed with signal
SIGPIPE. You will have to decide if this short delay is good enough for
you. It depends how noisy the first few milliseconds of the sound file are.

---

If your `ffplay` does not respond to SIGPIPE, you can run your own
kill command by noting the process id of the command in a temporary file
`pidfile`.
Note the use of `$BASHPID` rather than `$$`, as the latter does not change within a sub-shell.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sound=somefile.wav
touch flagfile
(sleep 4; rm -f flagfile) &
( echo $BASHPID >pidfile
  exec ffplay -nodisp -stats -loop 0 $sound 2>&1 ) |
while read -d $'\r' time rest
do  case $time in
    nan|-*|0.00) [ ! -f flagfile ] && break ;;
    esac
done
kill -hup $(<pidfile)
rm -f pidfile
```

Comment: Not bad. I found that occasionally the `nan` line is missing, but there is usually at least one if not two lines right after it, which have a negative value like -0.03s (as seen in your example output). Your bash script already accounts for this.  Just a little caveat: in my setup (Git bash on Windows), ffmpeg does not get killed on SIGPIPE, even after a very long time (over a minute).

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about Unix on Windows. I've added a version with an explicit kill.

Comment: I must admit, I do not follow the second version. What does the `kill -hup` actually do? AFAICS it sends HUP to ffmpeg, but that would kill ffmpeg either immediately or not at all, would it not?

Comment: To get to the `kill` command, the pipeline `ffplay|while...` has to finish first. This happens when the `case` statement matches as in the first version. On a match, if there is no flagfile, the `break` command causes the while loop to exit, and only then do we get to the kill.